# Medic abilities

Tags: pandemic

The medic card says that they can “remove ALL  cubes of one colour when doing Treat Disease”.

One interpretation from the rules is that Treat Disease applies only to the city you are in. However another implication from the above wording is that ALL the cubes of that colour wherever they may be on the board are removed.

Can someone help clarify this?

Comment: While it could the text could be clearer, the answer gives the universally-accepted reading of the rule (in my experience, which has seen many games with many people). This is already an extremely powerful ability with that reading.

Comment: And it can be confirmed by playing the app version, which definitely applies the effect only to the city the Medic is in.

Answer (score 23):

No, you can't remove every cube of the same colour from any location as the Medic - it is only all cubes of the same colour on the same location.

The rulebook (page 5 under the **Treat Disease** action) elaborates slightly further on the rule:

> The Medic may remove all the cubes of a single color (instead of 1) when performing the Treat Disease action.

It does not say from any location - it specifies when performing the Treat Disease action, where the Treat Disease action normally specifies:

> Remove a disease cube from the city your pawn occupies. (Each removed cube costs one action.)